# Script to order MySQL columns by name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few MySQL tables which are quite confusing as there are no order on the column sorting. I know it doesn't mean anything for the end-user, but sometimes it makes it harder for me when I want to add new columns.

So I'm looking for some kind of script that can order and move the columns around, so that it is saved not just a SELECT query. It will take forever it I has to do it manually one by one.

I know this:

```
select c.COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
where c.TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_name'
group by c.column_name 
order by c.column_name
```

But that is only a SELECT. Is there someway I can order the table, so it keeps being ordered by name?
If help is needed from PHP, that is possible.

Comment: Just curious- is adding more columns something you often find yourself wanting to do? I ask because it can be symptom of a poorly designed schema

Comment: It's a living system with more than 10 years behind it. The design schema may not be the smartest any longer, but with a system being used and new things coming up, sometimes a new column is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select c.COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
where c.TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_name'
group by c.column_name 
order by c.column_name desc
```

Comment: Sorry but did you read my question? I'm looking for at script that can alter the table based on column names, so that they are order alfanumeric.